# How to make paragraph alignment responsive?

Tags: html, css

Web view

[image]

Mobile view

[image]

How to make paragraphs well structured when in mobile view. My problem is that when in mobile view the paragraphs are out of order. I attached a picture for the mobile display paragraph. Can anyone help me how to make paragraphs in mobile view arranged like in web view.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.paragraph {
  color: #0E71B0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-item-right">
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 10%;">We understand the need for patients to have a better health care when they are going through their health journey.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">Anchored around cHEART patient app that keeps personal
    <br>health information (PHI), we have three (3) integrated <br> solutions to enable healthcare providers to provide <br> continuous care to their patients.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>SIMPLE</b> - an on-demand emergency medical care for pre-
    <br>hospital service.
  </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>24 Health</b> - a personalised on-demand medical care at home <br>after being discharged from hospital.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>EASY</b> - a digital solution for population health, catering to<br> the underserved community to help them screen and <br>maintain their health.</p>
  <a href="bookdemoform.html" target="popup">
    <button class="button2" style="  width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; "><b>Book a demo <br>
                    now</b></button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing those `<br>` tags would be a good start, IMO.

Comment: Is there any other way than removing the <br>. I use br so that the paragraph design follows my client's wishes.

Comment: Never use content (i.e. `<br>` tags) to define a look-and-feel. Instead e.g. set the parent container to a certain width to make the contained text run as wide as you wish.

Comment: "I use br so that the paragraph design follows my client's wishes" What does that mean? Line breaks are for just that, not for styling

Comment: Educate your client. This violates all semantic and responsive best practices. Also get those repetitive and messy inline styles into your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the 'br' tags.

Then add text-align: justify; to the .paragraph class

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.paragraph {
  color: #0E71B0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-item-right">
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 10%;">We understand the need for patients to have a better health care when they are going through their health journey.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">Anchored around cHEART patient app that keeps personal health information (PHI), we have three (3) integrated solutions to enable healthcare providers to provide continuous care to their patients. </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">
    <b>SIMPLE</b> - an on-demand emergency medical care for pre-hospital service.
  </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">
    <b>24 Health</b> - a personalised on-demand medical care at home after being discharged from hospital.
  </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">
    <b>EASY</b> - a digital solution for population health, catering to the underserved community to help them screen and maintain their health.
  </p>
  <a href="bookdemoform.html" target="popup">
    <button class="button2" style="  width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; ">
      <b>Book a demo  now </b>
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way than removing the <br> . I use br so that the paragraph design follows my client's wishes.

Comment: Yes, then you will have to delete the br tag only in the @media query.

Answer (score 0):

"Delete" `<br>` in `@media (max-width: 900px)`, with your permission, I'll just add this to your code...:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    flex-direction: row;
    
  }
  
  .flex-item-left {
    background-color: #E9F1FF;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    flex: 50%;
  }
  
  .flex-item-right {
    background-color: #E9F1FF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: auto;
    flex: 50%;
  }

.paragraph{
    color: #0E71B0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }


 @media (max-width: 900px) {
    .flex-container {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
     /*  */
     .paragraph br{
         content:' ';
     }
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-item-right" >
    <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 10%;">We understand the need for patients to have a better
        health care when they are going through their health journey.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">Anchored around cHEART patient app that keeps personal
        <br>health information (PHI), we have three (3) integrated <br>
        solutions to enable healthcare providers to provide <br> continuous care to their patients.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>SIMPLE</b> - an on-demand emergency medical care for
        pre-<br>hospital
        service.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>24 Health</b> - a personalised on-demand medical care at
        home <br>after
        being discharged from hospital.</p>
    <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>EASY</b> - a digital solution for population health,
        catering to<br>
        the underserved community to help them screen and <br>maintain their health.</p>
    <a href="bookdemoform.html" target="popup">
        <button class="button2" style="  width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; "><b>Book a demo <br>
                now</b></button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `br` tags and then use property `text-align` and give it the value `justify`. Justify is the arrangement of sentences or documents that are aligned right and left. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the need for `<br>`'s if you define a width that forces the paragraphs to wrap at about the same point as your manually added `<br>`s did.

In the demo below a width of 49 [ch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#:%7E:text=The%20advance%20measure%20(width)%20of%20the%20glyph%20%220%22%20of%20the%20element%27s%20font.) `p {max-width:49ch;}` gives *almost* the same line breaks as your hard-coded version. I've put a version with and without your breaks so you can compare. You can also resize the container to see what it looks like responsively. See snippet below.

I've applied the max-width to the paragraphs but depending on your content it is probably preferable to set the max-width on the container instead.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: #E9F1FF;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.paragraph {
  color: #0E71B0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

section {
border:1px solid grey;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
.demo p {max-width:49ch;}
```

```html
<section>With BR's:
<div class="flex-item-right">
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">Anchored around cHEART patient app that keeps personal
    <br>health information (PHI), we have three (3) integrated <br> solutions to enable healthcare providers to provide <br> continuous care to their patients.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>SIMPLE</b> - an on-demand emergency medical care for pre-
    <br>hospital service.
  </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>24 Health</b> - a personalised on-demand medical care at home <br>after being discharged from hospital.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>EASY</b> - a digital solution for population health, catering to<br> the underserved community to help them screen and <br>maintain their health.</p>
</div>
Without BR's (max-width:49ch):
<div class="flex-item-right demo">
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;">Anchored around cHEART patient app that keeps personal health information (PHI), we have three (3) integrated solutions to enable healthcare providers to provide continuous care to their patients.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>SIMPLE</b> - an on-demand emergency medical care for pre-hospital service.
  </p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>24 Health</b> - a personalised on-demand medical care at home after being discharged from hospital.</p>
  <p class="paragraph" style="padding-top: 1%;"><b>EASY</b> - a digital solution for population health, catering to the underserved community to help them screen and maintain their health.</p>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right">Resize ↘</div>
<section>
```